# creating an object from mongoose queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can I make an object from the result of queries? In the meals, the table functions with queries to the database. How can I do this if queries are asynchronous?

```js
const returnResultOfQuery = () => {
  Dinner1300.count().exec(function (err, count) {

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
  
    Dinner1300.findOne().skip(random).exec(
      function (err, result) {
        console.log(result)
      })
  })
```

```js
const week = [
  {id: 1, day: 1},
  {id: 2, day: 2},
  {id: 3, day: 3},
  {id: 4, day: 4},
  {id: 5, day: 5},
  {id: 6, day: 6},
  {id: 7, day: 7},
]

const diet = week
  .map(value => ({
    id: value.id,
    day: value.day,
    meals: [
      returnResultOfQuery(),
      returnResultOfQuery(),
      returnResultOfQuery()
    ]
  }))

  console.log(diet)
```

Comment: Looks like your example doesn't work. Also, could you update your question to include the code for your Mongo queries? At this point it's impossible to answer your question because we don't know what your queries look like

Comment: i added query example

Answer (score 0):

you can use code, it is just promise wrapper

```
const returnResultOfQuery = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Dinner1300.count().exec(function (err, count) {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
        Dinner1300.findOne().skip(random).exec(
          function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(result);
        });
     });
  });
}

const week = [
  {id: 1, day: 1},
  {id: 2, day: 2},
  {id: 3, day: 3},
  {id: 4, day: 4},
  {id: 5, day: 5},
  {id: 6, day: 6},
  {id: 7, day: 7},
]

 const diet = Promise.all(week
    .map(value => ({
      id: value.id,
      day: value.day,
      meals: [
        returnResultOfQuery(),
        returnResultOfQuery(),
        returnResultOfQuery()
      ]
   }))
 );

console.log(diet)
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the way to achieve this, is first executing all the queries using `Promise.all` and once you have the results, create the new object. Something like:

```
const week = [
    { id : 1, day : 1 },
    { id : 2, day : 2 },
    { id : 3, day : 3 },
    { id : 4, day : 4 },
    { id : 5, day : 5 },
    { id : 6, day : 6 },
    { id : 7, day : 7 }
];

const returnResultOfQuery = () => {
    return Dinner1300.count ().exec ( function ( err, count ) { 
        const random = Math.floor ( Math.random () * count );

        return Dinner1300.findOne ().skip ( random ).exec (
            function ( err, result ) {
                console.log ( result );
                return result;
            } );
    } );
};

let promises = [];

for ( let x in week ) {
    promises.push ( returnResultOfQuery () );
    promises.push ( returnResultOfQuery () );
    promises.push ( returnResultOfQuery () );
}

let diet = [];

Promise.all ( promises ).then ( function ( result ) {
    let i = 0;
    for ( let x in week ) {
        diet.push (
            {
                id : x.id,
                day : x.day,
                meals : [
                    result[ i ],
                    result[ i + 1 ],
                    result[ i + 2 ]
                ]
            }
        );
        i = i + 3;
    }
} );

console.log ( diet );
```

**P.S:** I have not tested the above code.